# Run multiple node js app on digitalocean with different ports

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I have 2 node js app deploy to Digital Ocean (Ubuntu 16.04), I use pm2 for application management. I try to use nginx as a web server but now I want to run 2 app with different port for example:

- App 1: http://my_ip:3001
- App 2: http://my_ip:3002

I try to config nginx but it seem not work:

```
server {
    listen 3001;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; //Node app
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It work only on port 80.
What configuration I need to do for this problem? Thanks

**UPDATE: Just using ufw to open the ports**